# Bash script to backup modified file in a particular folder structure

Tags: linux, bash

I have a folder structure from there i am backing up files which are modified 
Below is folder structure

```
/home/aaditya/customer/jiva/foo/bar/File1.txt
```

Using below command i want to backup File1.txt file

```
 cd /home/aaditya/customer/jiva/foo/bar
 tar -zcvf archive_backup_folder.tar.gz File1.txt
```

But my problem statement is that when i unzip the tar archive_backup_folder, File1.txt should be there inside `customer/jiva/foo/bar/File1.txt` not only `File1.txt`
Can anybody help me how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Just do:

```
cd /home/aaditya/
tar -zcvf archive_backup_folder.tar.gz customer/jiva/foo/bar/File1.txt
```

That is, include the path structure in the archive.

Comment: Hi Kaylum, thanks for the reply but i don't want make folder structure hardcoded i have given simple example but in reality from /home/aaditya i am navigating each folder or sub folder to find any modified files are there or not if it is there i am backing up files

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this

```
TIME=`date +%b-%d-%y`
FILENAME=backup-$TIME.tar.gz
SRCDIR= directory or file that has to be backed up
DESDIR= place where you need to store it
tar -cpzf $DESDIR/$FILENAME $SRCDIR
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 cd /home/aaditya/
 find customer -mtime -1 -exec tar -rvf test.tar {} \;
```

the "find" command will find out all files modified within 1 day and for each of them, run "tar -rvf test.tar the_file" to add it to test.tar (you way want to "rm -f test.tar" before running the "find" command